# how to extract .NET object from excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, object, blazor-server-side

i find this article with dll to map excel file to object or list of object

[exceltoObjectConvertor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1235693/Extract-NET-Object-from-Excel-WorkSheet?msg=5812158#xx5812158xx)

All work good in my local machine with visual studio but i published it to my QA server the ligne below dont work, and return me nothing ...

```
string filePath = @"your excel file path"; 
List<WorkSheetInfo> workSheetList = ExcelXMLConvertor.GetWortSheetsInfo(filePath);
```

The problem seems to come from the GetWortSheetsInfo function, but dont understand why its working well in my local machine and not in my server QA...
i check evrething twice or more, the file path etc...
any ideas?

Comment: Does your QA server have Excel installed on it? The package uses Microsoft's Excel interop

Comment: thanks for your idea @BenSampica , i really dont know i have to check with my collegue... You think it can be because of that? I should have excel installed on the server to make it work?

Comment: You must... yes.

Comment: i just saw on the server that excel is installed ... so i dont understand ... :-(  do we need to give permission and right to my webapp to use excel from IIS or something like that? @BenSampica

Comment: Nope. I’d verify your application has access to wherever it’s trying to read the Excel from, too. Otherwise, you’ll want to check server logs and see if any exceptions are showing up from your application.

Comment: thanks @BenSampica its very sad cause its working well on my local machine and save me time and code to extract what i need as an object from the excel document ... but no working on server so strange .. :-( 
i think the app has access to the forlder cause it can see what there is inside when i made a loop inside it give me the exact names files there are, and also the one that i need to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution more popular on the nugetPackage Manager called ExcelMapper
simple to use
[ExcelMapperGithub](https://github.com/mganss/ExcelMapper)
Hope it will help ;-)